# Error writing to file when installing SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, installation

I got this error in installing SQL Server 2008 R2:

The following error has occurred:

> Error writing to file: Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Controls.DLL.   Verify that you have access to that directory.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try re-installing SQL from command prompt.

Comment: now I got this error:  Unable to open Windows Installer file 'I:\SQL2008\Developer\x86\setup\sql_engine_core_shared_msi\sql_engine_core_shared.msi'.

Windows Installer error message: The system cannot open the device or file specified.

Answer (score 0):

Please install Microsoft .Net Framework 4.0 from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=17718) and try installing SQL Server 2012.